# Get string between parentheses, excluding other Parentheses

Tags: java, regex

I have a mathematical expression as a string, for example:
(5 + 4) - 5 - (6 - (3 - 4) + (5 - (3 - 6)))

I am trying to use regex to extract the expression within parentheses that don't contain other parentheses. In this case it would (5 + 4), (3 - 4), (3 - 6).

I think there are two possible ways:
1. Exclude matches that also contain parentheses or
2. Only include matches where the string contains a number or +,-,/,* ie. (3*4), (5/6), (3), etc...

So far I have:

```
    String ex = "(5 + 4) - 5 - (6 - (3 - 4) + (5 - (3 - 6)))";
    String match = "";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(([^\\)]+)\\)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ex);
    if(matcher.find()){
        match = matcher.group();
    }
```

I only get (5 + 4) with this though. I'm very new to regex so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: is using regex mandatory? you can accomplish it with a stack

Comment: Well eventually this will be converted to a stack, so I'm certainly open for that. How would this be implemented?

Comment: i'm writing a stack solution

Comment: actually the stack is used when you need to evaluate the entire expression, like calculators do. For just extracting the regex seems fine. Using stack: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/expression-evaluation/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must iterate over all the matches using `while` instead of `if`

```
String ex = "(5 + 4) - 5 - (6 - (3 - 4) + (5 - (3 - 6)))";
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(([^\\)]+)\\)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(ex);
while (matcher.find()){
    matches.add(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Note that I'm using `matcher.group(1)` then the result wil exclude the parentheses. Also I recomend using this RegEx

```
Pattern.compile("\\(([^\\(\\)]+)\\)"); //Excluding left parentheses too
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly!

Comment: @David I'm glad to help. Don't forget to accept this answer if it was useful for you :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you were pretty close. From what I tested this should work:

```
\([^\(\)]+\)
```

Which basically says "match a '(', any number of characters that are NOT '(' or ')', and then another ')'.

Although, parsers often employ a stack structure for these kinds of tasks. Iterate through the string, push whenever you see a '(' and pop when you see a ')' and store the stuff in-between. I'm generalizing a lot there, but you get the idea. A nice side effect is you can easily build validation into it: if you ever try to pop on an empty stack, or end with elements still in the stack that means you have a hanging parenthesis in your expression.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly too (I'm pretty sure it's the same regex as DSantiagoBC posted. I am curious about the stack implementation though.

Would I have to add each character to a stack first, via for loop?

Comment: Yep looks to be the same. If your end goal is to evaluate the expression,  @nandsito is pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: Also look into Recursive Descent Parsers